# Hide element issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

So I am trying to hide a DIV that sits inside a td. Issue I am facing is that the attached code fades the div perfect fine but the table space stays there. How do I make this table space disappear completely?

Table:

```
<table width="100%" id="myTabDiv">
    <tr><td align="center"><div id="innerDiv"> This disappears  </div></td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: By 'the table space' do you mean the table cell <td> or the entire table

Comment: I meant the entire table.

Comment: Is jquery an option?

Comment: No it's not an option :-(

Comment: Could you use this? document.getElementById('myTabDiv').style.display='none';
Or do you need to fade?

Comment: @TylerOlson does the same thing. Table disappears but content before this table (another table) doesn't move up to the place where disappeared table was

Comment: @radwebjava What if you wrap the table in another div and hide that div instead?

Comment: @TylerOlson Wow.. Thanks. enclosing in another div did the trick. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @radwebjava It's possible that the table can't have that css element, but if its parent div is hidden, it can't be shown? I'm not positive though :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, the solution was to wrap the table in another div and hide that div instead.